Join texts and optimize formatting
I have text objects (text1, text2, etc) with formatting information (eg. [bold, italic]). Now I want to concat these texts and format them in HTML.
For a simple case it would transform the following
text1[bold,italic]
text2[]
text3[bold]

into this HTML:
<b><i>text1</i></b>
text2
<b>text3</b>

But I want to join formattings where possible, not format each text individually. For example the following
text1[bold,italic]
text2[bold]
text3[]

Should result in this HTML:
<b>
  <i>text1</i>
  text2
</b>
text3

Additionally I want to wrap the "longest" formatting to the "outside" of the DOM. For example in the following case, italics is the longer formatting chain and thus wraps around the bold element:
text1[bold,italic]
text2[italic]
text3[]

Result:
<i>
  <b>text1</b>
  text2
</i>
text3


What would be a good algorithmic approach to solve this problem? Answers in pseudocode or any programming language would be helpful.

How many different formatting information do you have?

No sure why it matters, but about 5 or 6.

Here is the solution I used in the end. Thanks for all input here and elsewhere. It got me on the right track.
The solution has two parts.
Output
To output the tags, a stack based approach is used. You loop over the items and close all formattings that are not in the current item (removing the formatting and all intermediaries from the stack):
// close all formatting that is not in the current text
$toclose = array_diff($fStack, $formatting);
foreach($toclose as $f) {
    // we need to make sure all formatting is closed, but we close by popping the
    // stack. This ensures we don't create invalid nesting
    while (in_array($f, $fStack)) {
        $result .= $this->closeFormatting(array_pop($fStack));
    }
}

Then we open all formatting that is still missing on the stack and add it to the stack:
// open formatting that is in the current text but not yet open
$new = array_diff($formatting, $fStack);
foreach ($new as $f) {
    $result .= $this->openFormatting($f);
    $fStack[] = $f;
}

Finally you can output the text itself.
$result .= $text->__toString();
```php

After the loop close all remaining formattings on the stack.

```php
// close remaining formatting
while ($fStack) {
    $result .= $this->closeFormatting(array_pop($fStack));
}

Find the longest chains
The above approach will already work, but the tags might not be ideally nested. Eg. for
text1[bold,italic]
text2[italic]
text3[]

It might produce <b><i>text1</i></b><i>text2</i>text3. It depends on which formatting you found first in $formatting for the first item.
To solve this problem, we need to sort the formatting information by longest chain.
Eg. the above information should be:
text1[italic, bold]
text2[italic]
text3[]

To achieve that, I do a simple chain sorting step beforehand. You go backwards through the texts (starting at the second to last) and give it the information of how many same formattings come afterwards. You then sort the formatting by chain length (highest first).
The above would end up as something like this:
text1[italic:2, bold:1]
text2[italic:1]
text3[]

loop:
function updateFormattingScores()
{
    $len = count($this->texts);
    if($len < 2) return;
    for($i = $len - 2; $i >= 0; $i--) {
         $this->texts[$i]->updateFormattingScores($this->texts[$i + 1]);
    }
}

update:
public function updateFormattingScores(TextRun $nextRun)
{
    $next = $nextRun->getFormatting();
    foreach ($next as $key => $value) {
        if($this->formatting[$key] === 0) continue; // we don't have this format
        $this->formatting[$key] += $value; // add follow up chain
    }

    // sort by value, longest chains first
    arsort($this->formatting);
}

With this run before the output, the output will always find the longer chain formatting first.

For minimizing the total number of tags you have to write, the simple greedy algorithm is optimal.  At each position in the text:

If any formatting is turning off, write out end tags matching the preceding start tags until all the required formatting is turned off; then
Write start tags for any formatting that needs to turn on, in descending order of the length of the following text that it covers.


I'm going to describe the logic and provide pseudocode.  If you want a powershell or C# implementation, please let me know.
I would start by building a couple of helper functions.

parseline(line_num) - A function that can pull one line from the input and extract the text and the modifiers and returns an object with text and an array of modifiers.  This is probably a regex that builds the object.
searchline(modifier,start_line) - A function that can search lines starting from a given line for those matching a given modifier.  This one calls the above on the target line and compares from the resulting object.  This should return the number of subsequent lines that match that modifier.

Then, you need a counter to track the highest unprocessed line number (0 to linecount - 1)
Create two lookup tables with the HTML tags for each modifier.  HTMLmodifierStart has the start tags and HTMLmodifierEnd has the closing HTML tags for each modifier
Optional: code to preprocess the input and convert it from text to an array of objects using the first helper function on each line.
Main loop
counter=0
while (counter < linecount)
{
    current_modifiers=parseLine(counter).modifiers
    hashtable={}
    foreach (current_modifier in current_modifiers)
    {
        # build a hash table with each current modifier and the count
        # of subsequent lines matching that modifier
        hashtable[current_modifier]=searchLine(current_modifier,counter)
    }
    # work from highest to lowest modifiers by count
    # and build HTML in the output
    sorted_hashtable=sort hashtable by count descending
    # Add all opening modifier tags
    foreach (modifier in sorted_hashtable)
    {
        output+=HTMLmodifierStart[modifier]
    }
    reverse_sorted_hashtable=sort hashtable by count ascending
    # Add the text from the lines for the shortest modifier block
    # Finish with the closing HTML tag for that modifier
    foreach (modifier in reverse_sorted_hashtable)
    {
        current=counter
        while(current < counter+modifier.count)
        {
            output+=parseLine(current).text
            current++
        }
        # Add closing HTML tag
        output+=HTMLmodifierEnd(modifier)
    }
    # Increment the counter by the largest modifier processed
    counter+=largest number of lines in sorted_hashtable
}

